# What's wrong with my meteor/meteorite packages "require is not defined"?

Tags: meteor

meteor was working pre 0.6.5, but has stopped working since I updated. What would cause this error? Note that I have what I assume are the latest of stripe, fibers, and meteor.

```
> npm ls stripe
/path/to/project
└── stripe@1.3.0 

> npm -g ls fibers
/usr/local/lib
└── fibers@1.0.1 

> meteor --version
Release 0.6.5.1

> meteor
[[[[[ /path/to/project ]]]]]

=> Meteor server running on: http://localhost:3000/
W20130909-13:34:19.787(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/pabo/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20130909-13:34:19.867(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20130909-13:34:19.867(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20130909-13:34:19.868(-7)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: require is not defined
W20130909-13:34:19.868(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/node_modules/stripe/test/charges.js:1:47
W20130909-13:34:19.868(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/node_modules/stripe/test/charges.js:65:3
W20130909-13:34:19.868(-7)? (STDERR)     at mains (/path/to/project/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:153:10)
W20130909-13:34:19.868(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20130909-13:34:19.869(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/pabo/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20130909-13:34:19.869(-7)? (STDERR)     at /path/to/project/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:80:5
=> Exited with code: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly understand why, but I had to move my node_modules up a few directories to get this working again. I had done an

```
npm install stripe
```

in my main meteor project directory, which is apparently a bad thing. I'd still love to hear from people smarter than I about what exactly as going on, and what exactly I misunderstood to cause this in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you place in your project folder is considered a part of your Meteor application (with the only exception of `/tests` folder). That includes npm packages you install inside `npm_modules`. And most of the time plain npm packages are not designed to work inside Meteor file structure, hence they throw errors all over the place.

Running `npm install package` in upper level directory, or manually moving `npm_modules` higher in the structure is a bad idea either. That way you create an application that only works on your machine, as it depends on specific version of a npm package, and that dependency is nowhere stated. You'll run into problems during deployment. On a VPS you'd need to install the same packages, for Heroku you'd need a custom buildpack, and so on.

The correct way to use npm packages in Meteor app is currently [`npm` meteorite package](http://atmospherejs.com/package/npm). It's easy to use and well documented under that link.